# Bug panel.VerticalScroll.Maximum?

Tags: .net, vb.net, scroll, panel

I have found a very annoying bug in `VB (2013)` and I need a work around to solve this.

When a panel has a `scroll` `length` value greater than the `panel` `height`,  the `panel.VerticalScroll.Maximum`  should be set to this total height otherwise it should be the `height` of the `panel`.

From what I can see, if a `panel` is < 100px, `VerticalScroll.Maximum`  has a default value of 100px which is a stupid thing to do in the first place because it's default should clearly be the height of the panel.

For Example:
When my empty panel loads, it is 60px in height, `panel.VerticalScroll.Maximum` is 100

When I load controls into the panel - provided that 1 of the controls is positioned extending through or postioned on/after pixel 60 then the `panel.VerticalScroll.Maximum` gets set to the correct value > 60

But if I only load controls into the panel that don't extend past 60px, the `panel.VerticalScroll.Maximum` stays at 100!

I have tried setting this value on `form load` and in the `designer` but it doesn't work.
Loading the controls or putting them in the designer causes the same effect,  only when a control extends past the height of the panel it then fires the maximum to be set.

This would be alright if the default was set to the height of the `panel`, but its not when the `panel` is < 100px in height

This is nothing to do with `Scroll Bars`,  I know about `LargeChange` issue etc, this is not using a `scroll bar`.

The code is part of a much larger project and isn't extractable, but if you need, I will write a small demo if needed

Comment: Not a downvoter, but it would help if you got rid of the rant and just focus on the question.  It's not clear why this is a problem.  Consider using a FlowLayoutPanel instead.

Comment: its a fiddly problem to explain.    i cant use anything but a panel in this situation.  
More simply -  a max value should not have a default minimum that is greater than the object.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `AutoScroll` to `false` on the panel.

I opened up the `Maximum` setter on `System.Windows.Forms.ScrollProperties` and found that the following was the first check in the setter:

```
if (this.parent.AutoScroll)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: that stops the panel from being able to scroll so isnt useful.  Is there any i can force  .Maximum to be recalculated?